# Effects of using $routeProvider for routing

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, routes, ejs

I am using AngularJS 1.2.21.

As long as I am using NodeJS with Express for routing for serving `ejs` pages, everything works fine, but if once I start using `$routeProvider` for routing using `ng-view`, some of the CSS and jQuery doesn't seem to work properly.

For example: css style for checkbox is gone and the default checkbox of the browser overrides and jQuery RateIt plugin stops working.

Could somebody help me understand why it might be happening?

Comment: May be show your `$routeProvider` config might help other people to help you easier.

Comment: @runTarm: I was having issues with jQuery plugin not being initialized properly as I was using `ng-view` attribute. Thanks for the reply.